# How to keep last half parentheses line by line after fomating in flutter code?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using intellij idea.My flutter code after formating:

```
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            home: Scaffold(
                backgroundColor: Colors.purple[50],
                appBar: AppBar(
                  title: Text('I AM RICH'),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
                ),
                body: Center(
                    child: Image(
                  image: NetworkImage(
                      'https://df2sm3urulav.cloudfront.net/tenants/gr/uploads/content/4wmnqlctgu0f3c9a.jpg'),
                ))));
      }
    }
```

But what i want is...

```
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            home: Scaffold(
                backgroundColor: Colors.purple[50],
                appBar: AppBar(
                  title: Text('I AM RICH'),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
                ),
                body:  Center(
                   child: Image(
                      image: NetworkImage(
                          'https://df2sm3urulav.cloudfront.net/tenants/gr/uploads/content/4wmnqlctgu0f3c9a.jpg'),
                    )
                )
            )
        );
      }
    }
```

The parentheses at the end stacks,i want them to be line by line.

Comment: put comma `,` after every `)` then

Comment: Add `comma`s like: `),),),)` and then format again